# MarkupSafe, SQLAlchemy and pycrypto fail because wheel build fail

Tags: python-2.7, setup.py, python-wheel

Running windows with python 2.7, setuptools, pip and wheel at latest release. Trying to install dependencies using

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

failing because "one or more wheels failed to build". 
Log:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: MarkupSafe, SQLAlchemy, pycrypto
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for MarkupSafe: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for MarkupSafe: finished with status 'error'
  .
  .
  .
  Failed to build wheel for MarkupSafe

  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for SQLAlchemy: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for SQLAlchemy: finished with status 'error'
  .
  .
  .
  Failed to build wheel for SQLAlchemy

  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pycrypto: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pycrypto: finished with status 'error'
  .
  .
  .
  Failed to build wheel for pycrypto

  Failed to build MarkupSafe SQLAlchemy pycrypto
```

(Removed complete output because over character limit but all reach a certain point then say some file is not found)

However according to http://pythonwheels.com/ there are no wheels for those packages so why is pip trying to build wheels for them?

Answer (score 0):

Try using python -m easy_install SQLAlchemy instead.